# Cannot save new record in join table with DOCTRINE

Tags: php, doctrine

I have tree tables: `delivery_providers`, `delivery_cost_schemas` and `delivery_cost_schemas_providers` that joins them. I created classes for each of them but I need to exclude `delivery_providers` from cascade persist.

```
#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'delivery_cost_schemas')]
class DeliveryCostSchema
{
    #[Id, Column(name: 'id', type: 'string'), GeneratedValue(strategy: "NONE")]
    public string $id;

    #[OneToMany(mappedBy: "deliveryCostSchema", targetEntity: DeliveryCostSchemaProvider::class, cascade: [
        "persist",
        "remove"
    ], orphanRemoval: true)]
    public ?Collection $costSchemaProviders = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
    }

    public function addProvider(DeliveryProvider $deliveryProvider): void
    {
        $this->costSchemaProviders->add(
            new DeliveryCostSchemaProvider(
                $this,
                $deliveryProvider
            )
        );
    }
}

#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'delivery_providers')]
class DeliveryProvider
{
    #[Id, Column(name: 'id', type: 'string'), GeneratedValue(strategy: "NONE")]
    public readonly string $id;

    #[OneToMany(mappedBy: "deliveryProvider", targetEntity: DeliveryCostSchemaProvider::class)]
    private Collection $costSchemaProviders;
}

#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'delivery_cost_schemas_providers')]
class DeliveryCostSchemaProvider
{
    #[Id, Column(name: 'id', type: 'string'), GeneratedValue(strategy: "NONE")]
    public string $id;

    #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: DeliveryCostSchema::class, inversedBy: "deliveryCostSchemaProviders")]
    #[JoinColumn(name: "schema_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
    private DeliveryCostSchema $deliveryCostSchema;

    #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: DeliveryProvider::class, inversedBy: "deliveryCostSchemaProviders")]
    #[JoinColumn(name: "provider_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
    private DeliveryProvider $deliveryProvider;

    public function __construct(
        DeliveryCostSchema $deliverySchema,
        DeliveryProvider $deliveryProvider,
    ) {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
        $this->deliveryCostSchema = $deliverySchema;
        $this->deliveryProvider = $deliveryProvider;
    }
}
```

I simplified my code.

```
$schema = new DeliveryCostSchema();
$provider = $this->deliveryProvidersRepository->getById($deliveryProviderId);
$schema->addProvider($provider);

$this->entityManager->persist($schema);
$this->entityManager->flush();
$this->entityManager->clear();
```

I get error on flush() and the error is:

> Multiple non-persisted new entities were found through the given association graph:

- A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchema#costSchemaProviders' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider@610. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider#__toString()' to get a clue.
- A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchema#costSchemaProviders' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider@606. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider#__toString()' to get a clue.
- A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchema#costSchemaProviders' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider@596. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider#__toString()' to get a clue.
- A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchema#costSchemaProviders' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider@470. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Modules\Shipping\Domain\Entities\DeliveryCostSchemaProvider#__toString()' to get a clue.